# Inequalities in category theory

Tags: category-theory, definition, relations

I am trying to understand the definition of a **relational $\beta$-module** as described here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relational+beta-module.

The definition given in section $2$ under the title "Bridge to a Concrete Description" is as follows:

A relational $\beta$-module is a set $S$ and a binary relation $\xi: \beta S \rightarrow S$ between ultrafilters on $S$ and elements of $S$ satisfying these requirements ( given by $(1)$ in the linked article),

[image]

**Question:** What does the inequality sign mean here?

I can't seem to find descriptions of this concept in the linked article or elsewhere.

Comment: I did not read the article but I would guess that it is because we work in the [2-poset of relations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Rel). So $1_S \leq u_S \xi$ means that $u_S \xi$ contains the identity relation. There is at most one arrow from one relation to an other, if the first is contained in the second. So we can just write $a \leq b$ to indicate that this arrow exists.

Comment: $\xi$ gives to $S$ the structure of an algebra for the $\beta$-monad, and the diagrams you wrote testify that the algebra axioms hold up to inequality (that can always be seen as a non invertible 2-cell in the 2-poset of relations, as already pointed out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in some of the comments, those diagrams take place in the category of sets and relations, $\operatorname{Rel}$. $\operatorname{Rel}$ isn't "just" a category: it's enriched over posets. That is, there isn't just a *set* of relations between sets $A$ and $B$, there's a *poset* of them (ordered by $\subseteq$).

The inequalities in the diagrams mean that they aren't intended to be commutative diagrams. Instead, they mean that the composition of relations on the left of the $\leq$ sign is contained as a subset of the composition of relations on the right (rather than equal to).